# Cores da imagem diferente quando aplicado em uma tag <video>

Tags: html, css

Estou usando um vídeo usando a biblioteca [material design bootstrap](https://mdbootstrap.com/plugins/jquery/video/)

O problema é que a qualidade do vídeo fica diferente quando eu rodo no browser e em um player de vídeo:

Imagem no browser:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Imagem no player de video:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**Meu codigo html:**

```
<section class="view intro-video">
  <a class="ancoraDesceConteudo" href="#sobreApp">
    <i class="fa fa-hand-o-down icondesceconteudo animated bounce infinite" aria-hidden="true"></i>
  </a>
  <video poster="https://i.imgur.com/3QIi6Xd.jpg" oncanplay="this.muted=true" playsinline autoplay muted loop>
    <source src=".../../assets/animals.mp4">
  </video>

</section>
```

**Meu css:**

```
.view img, .view video {
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    min-width: 100%!important;
}

.intro-video{
    height: inherit;
}

.ancoraDesceConteudo{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
}
```

Tem alguma técnica pra melhorar a imagem no browser ou alguma explicação que torne a imagem tão diferente assim no browser e no player?

Comment: Curioso isso. Já testei vários vídeos no navegador e nunca vi diferença quando rodado em um player :D

Comment: Me parece que vc aplicou algum `filter` no seu elemento, se não foi no vídeo talvez em algum elemento pai do vídeo...

Comment: Verifique se o material design bootstrap não está usando algum tipo de filtre como o @hugocsl comentou: https://mdbootstrap.com/docs/jquery/content/images/#overlays

Comment: Eu testei aqui e ficou normal. O problema é algum outro CSS que vc está usando ai. o MDB não coloca esse efeito por padrão nos vídeos não! Coloque o seu CSS inteiro ai que vai ajudar a te responder

Comment: Aparentemente é o navegador, quando uso o Opera a imagem fica mais clara, péssima, quando uso o firefox fica normal, queria saber como corrigir isso no opera, acho que é alguma configuração

Answer (score 0):

O que pode ser:

- O vídeo referenciado não está com qualidade boa; (vc disse que não é isso)
- Você aplicou algum filtro no elemento pai do vídeo ou no próprio vídeo;
- O vídeo tá com qualidade boa mas pra telas menores;

**Possíveis soluções:**

- Confira a questão dos filtros.
- Veja o tamanho do vídeo e se não o está expandindo demais.
- Na pior das hipósteses, upa o vídeo pro YouTube e referencia de lá.